# Eclipse error setting up Maven project for class exercise: Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have found a few related questions on this, but they're all related to Intellij or on Mac OS. I'm on Windows 8.1 and using Eclipse:

**Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600**

**Maven 3.3.1**

I've set up the "Run As" parameters [as directed for the course](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EO3pQ53DQP3SW4LCnOLiUtgAKCWbqXVprBWj0TOlRUM/pub#h.na9ph6i7k2gu) but I get the following error message when I try to run:

> -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.

My output for mvn -version is as follows, and seems to be correct.

> Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c;
>   2015-03-13T16:10:27-04:00)
>
> Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.1 Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle
>   Corporation
>
> Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre
>
> Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
>
> OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family:
>   "windows"

I'm a complete newb when it comes to Maven and Eclipse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happened if I dont have a Eclipse installed and Im getting this error message?

Answer (score 51):

Go to:
Window--> Preference --> Java --> Installed JREs --> Edit
In the edit Default VM arguments you need to put
If you already set the maven home, for Windows machine:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=M2_HOME
```

And for Linux and Mac OS X:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

In case you are using Maven 3.x, the variable is named $MAVEN_HOME

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$MAVEN_HOME
```

Comment: What happened if I dont have a Eclipse installed and Im getting this error message?

Comment: Thanks man. Have faced similar problem in Idea Intellij. You need to put the value in -> Edit configuration (from the maven run button) -> Go to the runner tab -> VM Options

Answer (score 16):

I managed to work out a solution for this.

1) I had to to to run configurations and add an argument to the VM. (Run - Run Configurations - JRE Tab - VM arguments). Enter the following in the text box

```
 -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME%
```

You need to use %M2_HOME% or something similar to represent the path to Maven, because when I added my path to that argument directly, it was unable to find it. I think it's because there is a length limit on the argument. My path was

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.1
```

and I got an error stating that it couldn't find the runtime at Program Files\Apache

2) Set up a system environment variable of called M2_HOME with C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.1

Control Panel - System and Security - System - Advanced System Settings - Environment Variables - System Variables - New

Comment: What happened if I dont have a Eclipse installed and Im getting this error message?

Answer (score 2):

You're not alone in encountering this. I recently moved to 3.3.1 as well and am encountering this same problem.

This isn't the best answer, but this will probably help you today.  Try moving back to the latest 3.2.x.  (Currently 3.2.5)

I have a feeling it's related to [MNG-5767](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5767) and a change that recently made it in.  There may be some functionality in an m2e update or it may have something to do with the structure of your maven project.  Without more detail, it's going to be difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your m2eclipse installation from https://www.eclipse.org/m2e will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

adding below to VM argument worked for me 
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=M2_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of maven will automatically set the multiModuleProjectDirectory property in the `bin/mvn` script. This was added [here](https://github.com/apache/maven/commit/8ed9a1caa8890773b45c6c408a4e40acf4f4b0fd), though I'm not sure how the release number/patching works. You can look for the `find_maven_basedir` function in that file. If it doesn't exist, try upgrading maven.

Answer (score 0):

Access the following location in eclipse

```
Window
  Preference
    Java
      Installed JREs
```

Now edit `Default VM arguments` and place below arguments according to your OS type.

**If Windows,**

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=M2_HOME
```

**If Linux,**

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```