# Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match

Tags: eclipse, maven

I just install a maven project into Eclipse.

```
Right click in the project -> Run As -> Maven clean
```

I got this error

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

but the variable is set, because going in the command line and typing set I see this:

```
M2_HOME=C:\PGM\apache-maven-3.3.3
M2=C:\PGM\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

Comment: You don't install a project, you import or create a project in Eclipse. I guess you meant imported here. Also, can you post the output (with error) of the build? If you try to run the build from the command line (and not from Eclipse) does it run successfully?

Comment: yes, sorry, imported from git. How can I buid it form the command line ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

Extracted from the following thread,  [Eclipse error setting up Maven project for class exercise: Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285148/eclipse-error-setting-up-maven-project-for-class-exercise-check-m2-home-enviro)

from Abhinav Kumar answer:

If u are getting error like -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match In eclipse then go through Window--> Preference --> Java --> Installed JREs --> Edit In the edit Default VM arguments you need to put If you already set the maven home. -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=M2_HOME (For Windows machine) -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME (For Mac OS X)

Comment: Thanks, I would have never figured this out on my own.