# Error: Could not find or load main class $MAVEN_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

while running maven clean I am getting the following error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class $MAVEN_HOME

while doing `mvn -version`  I got :

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:4
7+05:30)
**Maven home: D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..**
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

I have set `MAVEN_HOME = D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9`  in user variable in environment setting

Path in system variable in environment setting :  `D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin`

Since I am getting other error previously so I have done the following also as mentioned in this post:

[Eclipse error setting up Maven project for class exercise: Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285148/eclipse-error-setting-up-maven-project-for-class-exercise-check-m2-home-enviro)

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$MAVEN_HOME
```

I have consulted other links but still I am getting the error while running `MAVEN CLEAN` in eclipse juno

Comment: please note that maven home showing two dots (..) while doing mvn -version.Since I have also checked other links in which there is no two dots in maven home or m2_home

Comment: Sometimes I have to add curly brackets `${MAVEN_HOME}`
That said, on Windows `mvn` seem to look for `M2_HOME` rather than `MAVEN_HOME`

Comment: i a using apache -maven 3.3.9 which uses maven home as can be seen in mvn -version

Comment: doing ${MAVEN_HOME} is not working still showing the same error

Comment: Try to remove /bin from MAVEN_HOME. That environment variable needs to point to the Maven dir, not the bin inside it.

Comment: I have also done that but still showing the same error

Comment: I have also tried $M2_HOME but still showing :Error: Could not find or load main class $M2_HOME

Comment: The two dots are odd. I'm not getting any dots if I run mvn -version. Oh, and on Windows, it's `%variable%`, not `$variable`

Comment: The above errored output you posted is for mvn clean ?

Comment: yes sir  WHIEL DOING MVN -CLEAN

Comment: By the way, I hardly ever use the user environment settings for these things, not that I think it'll change anything here, but try to move it to the system environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) worked for me with the 3.3.9 version. The only difference is :

1) Add both `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` variables in the Windows environment, and point it to your Maven folder (Note: I have added it to system variables)

[image: setting up environment variables]

2) Update PATH variable, append Maven bin folder – `%M2_HOME%\bin`, so that you can run the Maven’s command everywhere

Post output of `mvn –version` again if you face the issue. Also try running mvn clean from the command line and post the results.

Comment: dots are gone in mvn - version but error remains the same

Comment: some other information I would like  to share : pom is showing error and I ahve two jdk 5 and 7 in path variable

Comment: Remember to change `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$MAVEN_HOME` to `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_HOME%`.

$variable is for *nix OS'es, Windows uses %variable%

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class %MAVEN_HOME%

Comment: @user3907559 I have a doubt. Why is you mvn -version output showing Maven home: D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\ ..... why is bin being appended to it. Could you search your project/pom if it was forced to this value somewhere else ?

Comment: What happens when you run mvn clean from the command line and not eclipse ?

Comment: What does `dir %MAVEN_HOME%` give you? Something tells me you have a problem with the resolution of your variables. Side note; Windows command lines only read the environment variables when opened. You have to close the command line and open a new one if you made changes to the environment variables.

Comment: D:\Web Projects\SpringSecurity>mvn -clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO
[INFO] Building SpringSecurity 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-28T23:04:12+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "lean". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase

Comment: D:\Web Projects\SpringSecurity>dir %MAVEN_HOME%
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6690-768A

 Directory of D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9

10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          .
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          ..
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          bin
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          boot
10-11-2015  11:38    <DIR>          conf
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          lib
10-11-2015  11:44            19,335 LICENSE
10-11-2015  11:44               182 NOTICE
10-11-2015  11:38             2,541 README.txt

Comment: D:\Web Projects\SpringSecurity>dir %MAVEN_HOME%
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6690-768A

 Directory of D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9

10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          .
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          ..
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          bin
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          boot
10-11-2015  11:38    <DIR>          conf
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          lib
10-11-2015  11:44            19,335 LICENSE
10-11-2015  11:44               182 NOTICE
10-11-2015  11:38             2,541 README.txt

Comment: GUYS COLULD YOU PLEASE TELL ME hOW TO PASTE THE DATA IN FORMATTED WAY

Comment: no sir it is showing me Error: Could not find or load main class %MAVEN_HOME%

Comment: To format, use the back tick character ` before and after the formatted text. Sadly these comments can't have new lines.

Comment: dir resolved it. But did you set MAVEN_HOME in that commandline earlier, or does it come from the environment variable dialog? Another thing `mvn -clean` is wrong, it's just `mvn clean` without the -

Comment: Sir I am changing the same variable MAVEN _HOME  in enviornment setting every time

Comment: ~ Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6690-768A

 Directory of D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9

10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          .
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          ..
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          bin
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          boot
10-11-2015  11:38    <DIR>          conf
10-11-2015  11:44    <DIR>          lib
10-11-2015  11:44            19,335 LICENSE
10-11-2015  11:44               182 NOTICE
10-11-2015  11:38             2,541 README.txt
               3 File(s)         22,058 bytes
              ~

Comment: SORRY i AM NOT ABLE TO FORMAT

Comment: I can still read it, and it tells me that the MAVEN_HOME is working there. Try to do what  Shubham Mittal suggested in the answer above. Define both MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME in the system environment and restart Eclipse the settings have been saved clicking OK on the environment dialogue.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class %MAVEN_HOME% I am still getting the error in eclipse .should I change it to $MAVEN_HOME

Comment: No. But I have never had to use variables in my `eclipse.ini`. However the article you link to doesn't use $ or %, it just says 
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=M2_HOME` for windows. which I find somewhat odd.

Comment: you have to tell eclipse where Maven has been installed so that it can use the Maven installation to build our projects. See my new answer

Comment: Grandt  please follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285148/eclipse-error-setting-up-maven-project-for-class-exercise-check-m2-home-enviro

Comment: Grandt I am getting this errror If I don't follow that link : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but that's for Linux and Mac OSX.

Comment: So what should I do to resolve this error in windows 7 32  bit :  -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.

Comment: Sorry Grandt I got your point but for windows even doing that stll taking me to same error:  
Error: Could not find or load main class M2_HOME

Comment: Treat the `$M2_HOME` part as a typo, and assume it means `%M2_HOME%`. But I'm drawing a blank here. I've never been asked about that variable. Try the answer on this one then, but remember to change `$M2_HOME` to `%M2_HOME%` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class %M2_HOME%

Comment: Weird. Why would it be looking for a class, when you are giving it a path. 
`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME%` with no spaces before and after =.

Comment: The `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME%` is in the eclipse.ini I hope, and not in the pom.xml

Comment: Grandt I am not manully making this assignment : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME% .I am doing thiese setps in eclipse : Go to: Window--> Preference --> Java --> Installed JREs --> Edit In the edit Default VM arguments you need to put If you already set the maven home, for Windows machine:

Comment: Try `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\mavenSecurity\apache-maven-3.3.9` though I'n not sure if the backslash need to be escaped so if that fails, try `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\\mavenSecurity\\apache-maven-3.3.9` or `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:/mavenSecurity/apache-maven-3.3.9`

Comment: Not Working any of these

Comment: I'm very sorry then, I wish I could help, but I'm all out of ideas. :(

Comment: Thanks for the effort you have to put .Thanks Grandt

Comment: Anybody can help to resolve this issue mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1):

configuring Maven on Eclipse. you have to tell eclipse where Maven has been installed so that it can use the Maven installation to build our projects.

[image]

Win 7 64 . Here is how i did my config.

[image]

Comment: It's weird, I've never had to do this. By the way, on the new Eclipse Neon it defaults to `Embedded  3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931`

Comment: True, its embedded when you work with the maven plugin for eclipse. I think so though

Comment: I have change it to the directory pointed to my maven location.BUt still error does not gone